# Using cocos2d-js for building mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cocos2d-js

Is it good way to use Cocos2d-JS for building applications (not games) for mobile platform or it is only for games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cocos2d-js Engine just makes sense for games or applications that just present Text, Sprites that you scroll through.
If you want to make normal applications have a look at [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) ;)